# Javascript: displaying fancy alerts with javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

- I have an Javascript file(`handler.js`) while is basically an ajax request/response cycle
- On receiving data, I do `alert(data)` and it works fine
- I want to show fancy alerts like one in Jquery, how can I create fancy alerts from with in `handler.js`?

Comment: What do you mean by "fancy alerts"? Are you talking about [jQuery UI's dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)?

Comment: You can [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) this so we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want handle errors.

Setup error handler using jQuery.ajax() options

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Then in the error callback use some sort of UI library, like jQuery UI, to display the dialog window.

jQuery Tools overlay might be more lightweight alternative than including the whole jQuery UI just for one dialog.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html